# onchange event on selecting item from dropdown list does not change state on setState and useState on first time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I cannot get the `curentProduct` to change to target value when I select prod from dropdown. It only happens when I select something again and the first product populates. I want it to change when I select something so the rate can be set automatically if I choose a product.
Here is my component

```
const [curentProduct, setCurrentProduct] = useState({
        id: null,
        catagory: "",
        name: "",
        rate: null,
        quantity: null
    })

const [productList, setList] = useState([some array of objects])

function handleProductChange(evt) {
    setCurrentProduct({
        id: null,
        catagory: "",
        name: evt.target.value,
        rate: (find object with param passed and get the rate),
        quantity: (value from the input)
    })
    console.log(console.log(curentProduct.name))
}
```

here is my HTML

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col"></th>
    <th scope="col col-6">
        <select name="products" id="products"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            onChange={(e) => handleProductChange(e)}
        >
            <option hidden disabled selected value> Select a Product </option>
            {products}
        </select>
    </th>
    <th scope="col" style={{ width: "100px" }}>
        <input type="number" id="quantity" style={{ width: "100%" }} />
    </th>
    <th scope="col" style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
        <label className="lead" id="rate">
            {curentProduct.rate ?? ""}
        </label>
    </th>
    <th scope="col" style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
        <label className="lead" id="amount">
            {/* {this.state.currentSelection.rate * this.state.currentSelection.quantity} */}
        </label>
    </th>
    <th scope="col" style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
        <button type="button" onClick className="btn btn-dark"><b>+</b>
        </button>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your console log will not work because of how React works with useState. It only updates after console.log() has been made, it should update on screen tho.

Edit: Awnser for comment

You are probably trying to put an Object directly into the render, that doesnt work.

```js
const obj = {title: "Lord of the Rings", description: "A long long time ago in a galaxy far away"}

//doesnt work
<div>{obj}</div>

//works
<div>
  <h4>{obj.title}</h4>
  <p>{obj.description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. I keep getting this 
   
 react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, catagory, name, rate}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.